# Want the position of Zoomed Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiscrollview

In my iPad app I want to zoom an image, and, if somebody scrolls the zoomed image for viewing I want to display the portion of the image seen by the person in another image view with a square frame, just like the image below with the red box.

I know I can get scroll and zoom values, but how can I get the position?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you are zooming it but better way is to use

1. UIScrollView
2. Add imageview to it
3. Use scrollview's delegate methods like

   - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   - (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
   - (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale

You can get zoomed area by ScrollView.contentOffset.x and y. Then use UIGraphic to draw rectange it will be something like this

```
GRect rect // original frame
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Refer following link for drawing rectangle: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

after finishing drawing rectangle you can get image with rectange by following function

```
IImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
//show above image in another imageview
```

Comment: no you dont understand the question well. I have to display user when he is srolling the zoom image in which part he is in another small image